# R: Why creating a combination [c()] of numbers is not straight forward when using variables?

Tags: r, list, combinations

So I do the following:

```
ii<-1
c(1:4, ii+4:ii+7)
```

and get the following back:

```
[1]  1  2  3  4 12 11 10  9
```

Then,... I think, oook, somehow R inverts things... let me try:

```
c(1:4, ii+7:ii+4)
```

and get the following!:

```
[1]  1  2  3  4 12 11 10  9  8  7  6
```

Total nonsense, right?
I got it to work by forcing R's arm in the following way:

```
c(1:4, I(ii+4):I(ii+7))
```

And finally got what I was waiting for:

```
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

**Why is this happening?**

P.S., Using R ver. 3.1.1 under Windows

Comment: `ii+(4:ii)+7` you're messing up some brackets there

Comment: try `7:4` to see what is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has to do with order of operations.

```
ii<-1
# These two are equivalent.
c(1:4, ii+4:ii+7)
c(1:4, ii + (4:ii) + 7)

# This is what you expected.
c(1:4, (ii+4):(ii+7))
```

Comment: thanks, got it. Makes sense that  " : " comes before math operators.